# Jquery dropdown menu moves when hovering over it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a drop down menu to my website. In the nav bar In the "About" section I want a drop down menu to appear when I hover over it. What happens is that my entire nav bar moves down a bit and the drop down menu barely appears. More specifically when I hover over the "About" portion of the nav bar it begins to move up and down spontaneously. Any help would be appreciated. Please see my code below for details:

Html

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>



    <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="parent">
              <li class="links"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#about">About</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li>Cusine</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                </ul> 
              </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
}

.links{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color:pink;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 150px;
}



li a {
    /*font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;*/
    font-family: "Verdana",Sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#A8004D;
}

li a:hover {
    /*addatransition animation*/
    background-color: pink;
    color:white;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.child{
    display:none;
    width: 100%!important;
}

ul.parent > li {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
}
```

js

```
 $(function() {
        $('ul.parent > li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('ul.child').show(200);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul.child').hide(400);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you give `150px margin` to both `ul elements` when only the ***first one*** is what you mean (I guess) So I modified the `child class` and set `margin to 0`. it stopped from moving around.

```js
 $(function() {
        $('ul.parent > li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('ul.child').show(200);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul.child').hide(400);
        });
    })
```

```css
#nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
}

.links{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color:pink;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 150px;
}



li a {
    /*font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;*/
    font-family: "Verdana",Sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#A8004D;
}

li a:hover {
    /*addatransition animation*/
    background-color: pink;
    color:white;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.child{
    display:none;
    width: 100%!important;
    margin-right: 0;
}

ul.parent > li {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="parent">
              <li class="links"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#about">About</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li>Cusine</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                </ul> 
              </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! I need to removed the bullets and adjust the padding. But everything works well so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 50px;

}

.links{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color:pink;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 150px;
}



li a {
    /*font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;*/
    font-family: "Verdana",Sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#A8004D;
}

li a:hover {
    /*addatransition animation*/
    background-color: pink;
    color:white;

}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.child{
    display:none;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: 12px;
    opacity:1;
}

ul.parent > li {
    float:left;
    width:30%;


}
<div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>



    <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="parent">
              <li class="links"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="links"><a href="#about">About</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li>Cusine</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                    <li>Info</li>
                </ul> 
              </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
 $(function() {
        $('ul.parent > li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('ul.child').show(200);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul.child').hide(400);
        });
    })
```